# Is there a way in Sheets/Apps Script to check if a Video Link in a cell will play?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, get, urlfetch

I have a long list of video files, some of which do not work.  I'm trying to find a way to quality check these and make sure all of them play.

I came across this script, which I thought worked perfectly.  However, I'm finding some video links that are BROKEN, but still return 200.

```
function getStatusCode(url) {
  var url_trimmed = url.trim();
  // Check if script cache has a cached status code for the given url
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  var result = cache.get(url_trimmed);
  
  // If value is not in cache/or cache is expired fetch a new request to the url
  if (!result) {

    var options = {
      'muteHttpExceptions': true,
      'followRedirects': false
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options);
    var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();

    // Store the response code for the url in script cache for subsequent retrievals
    cache.put(url_trimmed, responseCode, 21600); // cache maximum storage duration is 6 hours
    result = responseCode;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Is this possible? Is there a way based on the URL to see if a video link would play?

The broken URLs look like this, if it helps:

[image]

Comment: About `Is there a way based on the URL to see if a video link would play?`, I cannot know your video link. Can I ask you about the detail of the video link? For example, can you provide the sample video links of the valid and the invalid?

Comment: @Tanaike the video links I'm using are private unfortunately, but I do know a lot of them are broken because of special characters. This isn't always the case - my backup plan is to just use conditional formatting to call-out links with special characters, but was curious if it's possible to use a script like this to confirm if a video would play or not. Seems like it's probably not possible

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample broken video link so that we may test it? I have tried a portion of your code and it returned the value `404` when I set the value of `url` to a broken page link. However, I have not tried it on a video link if it works.